# SQL Server Why is geography::Point inside function non-deterministic?

Tags: sql-server, sql-function, sqlgeography

I store Latitude and Longitude (float null) data from the user, and want to create a persisted computed column of Geography data type based on these values (with the intention of using a spatial index on this column).

The computed column formula is:

```
(case when @lat IS NULL OR @lng IS NULL then NULL else [geography]::Point(@lat,@lng,(4326)) end)
```

This works as expected when persisted is set to true on the computed column (returns a Geography value when Latitude and Longitude are present, returns null otherwise.

However, I wish to abstract this into a user-defined function, as other tables will be using the same calculation. I have created the following function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetGeography] 
(
    @lat float null,
    @lng float null
)
RETURNS geography
AS
BEGIN   
    RETURN (case when @lat IS NULL OR @lng IS NULL then NULL else [geography]::Point(@lat,@lng,(4326)) end)
END
```

When I try to use this function in the computed column formula, and set persisted to true, I get the following error message:

```
Computed column 'Geog_LatLng' in table 'Tmp_Locations' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.
```

There is no documentation about the determinism of [POINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type?view=sql-server-2017), and the documentation on [Deterministic Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions?view=sql-server-2017) doesn't mention geography or point .

The short-term solution is to just replicate the formula across all tables, but I would like to know if it is possible to abstract the formula into a user-defined function.

Comment: I would suggest trying to create the function `with schemabinding` and see if that clears up your issue.

Comment: This may explain why you need schema binding: [The Halloween Problem](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/02/sql-plan/halloween-problem-part-4#schemabinding)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `with schemabinding`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetGeography] 
(
    @lat float null,
    @lng float null
)
WITH SCHEMABINDING -- <--- modified
RETURNS geography
AS
BEGIN   
    RETURN (case when @lat IS NULL OR @lng IS NULL then NULL else [geography]::Point(@lat,@lng,(4326)) end)
END
```

An explanation is in the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-2017#SchemaBound).